# Question about onListItemClick in ListActivity

Tags: android

I have a ListActivty and I overload the onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) in my List Activity.

My question is why onListItemClick() not getting called back (i have breakpoint in my debugger) when I have an ImageButton in my list item view (the one view created by my list adaptor from cursor)?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you clicking on the button or on the listview row. You might want to implement a click handler for your button too.

Comment: I am clicking on the listview, but the method onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) is not getting called back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the button's click occurring, but not the list item? This might be a focus problem where the button is taking the focus away from the list item. Try setting `myImageButton.setFocusable(false);`

Comment: I am also having this problem for my list with image buttons. I set myImageButton.setFocusable(false); but still not getting the event. Plz can anyone suggest the way to get the event..